# Error received using PSExec

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to use `PSExec`:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\servername -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\bin\service-control.bat --stop --all"
```

But I receive the following error:

```
.\PsExec.exe : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At line:1 char:1
+ .\PsExec.exe \\$vCenter -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe /c  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('C:\Program' is...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

operable program or batch file.

cmd.exe exited on <Server FQDN> with error code 1.
```

Comment: In which directory are you when you enter this command?

Comment: try with `.\PsExec.exe \\servername -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe /c '"C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\bin\service-control.bat --stop --all"'`

Comment: I cd to the same directory as where the psexec is located

Comment: What I have learned in stackoverflow is to avoid CD. Why wont you try to just put the long directory of the psexec. like `"C:\psexecFoldef\psexec.exe" \\servername -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\bin\service-control.bat --stop --all"`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the String formation. You need to wrap that in the single quotes to take the effect , like:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\servername -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe /c '"C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\bin\service-control.bat --stop --all"'
```

Comment: yeah. Exactly like my comment written few minutes before your answer...

Comment: @npocmaka: Could you please post that as an answer so that I can remove mine.

Comment: .\PsExec.exe -s \\$vCenter -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe /c '"C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\bin\service-control.bat --stop --all"'

.\PsExec.exe : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At line:1 char:1
+ .\PsExec.exe -s \\$vCenter -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('C:\Program' is...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
 .\PsExec.exe \\servername -u $user -p $password /accepteula cmd.exe /c '"C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\bin\service-control.bat --stop --all"'
```

the single quotes around the cmd command should tell the powershell to take the command as a string.